# does someone have a solution for "encryption unsuccessful" on redmi go?

Tags: boot

1. operating system ONLY working - stock
2. TWRP doesn't decrypt /data/
3. this solution doesn't work : http://www.electricbreadcrumbs.com/2012/07/guide-to-fixing-encryption-unsuccessful.html
4. deleting cache and data does NOTHING
5. doing factory reset only reboots
6. all ideas allowed (by me ;) )
7. maybe provide a link to really working system? as i saw most are having problems with hardware...
8. ... or a way ( with root ) to fully delete gApps - all apps and file managers can't do it...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138085/discussion-on-question-by-hacks-norris-does-someone-have-a-solution-for-encrypt).